# How do use the variable value in one method of class to another class in python

Tags: python

1) I am new in python . i just assign a variable in inside a method of one class and that variable need to access another class.
2) how will call the a method from one class to another class in python?

Comment: Could you write what you tried?

Comment: i just write two class ,inside the first class i declare a variable getdata = xxx. but i need this get data value to another class . what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to do something like this?

```
class one:
    def __init__(self):    
        self.x = 2
class two:
    def get1(self,reference):
        print reference.x

    def get2(self):
        global x
        print x.x
x = one()
y = two()
y.get1(x)
y.get2()
```

Which outputs:

```
2
2
```

Comment: thanks, how do i call a method from one class to another class

Comment: The same way- you have to refer to the object that is the instance of the class.  y is class two, so y.get1() is the get1 method in y.

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful but here's one way of doing it.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
         self.value = "from Foo"

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print Foo().value

Bar()
```

Another flavor

```
class Foo(object):

    def valuesForOtherClasses(self):
        self.value = "from Foo"

class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).valuesForOtherClasses()
        print self.value

Bar()
```